# connect ftp account with file_get_content function

Tags: php, ftp

I have an FTP account. I want to connect to FTP with **[file_get_contents](http://tr.php.net/manual/tr/function.file-get-contents.php)**. Is this possible? If not, how can I do it?

I want to do this for an upload script similar to hotfile or rapidshare.

Comment: When you say 'my account is cryptic' do you mean it is FTPS/SFTP?

Comment: @DaveRandom. no secured only password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do from your comments on @genesis' answer, what you need to do is this:

```
$file = file_get_contents("derpost:pass**@ftp1.freakshare.com/Freez%20Screen%20Vide‌​o%20Capture.lnk");

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.jpg"'); // Change file name as appropriate
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($file));
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); // Change this MIME type as appropriate

echo $file;
```

Comment: but this is not only image. i want to use with "rar".

Comment: Are you getting the rar file from the same ftp server?

Comment: And how will you know which file you want to get? Will it be with `$_GET` or some other way?

Comment: application/x-rar-compressed is this rar type?

Comment: Yes, or you could use `application/octet-stream`. This is not technically correct, but it more or less guarantees the client will handle it right - you want the client simply download the file, not try and use it in any way, since the client will not understand how to work with a `.rar` file.

Comment: http://ebookdownload1.com/denemeler/deneme.php do you can try. this is very slow :(

Comment: I get an instant HTTP 500 error, which more than likely means you have syntax error in you PHP file...

Comment: @Yusufali let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2715/discussion-between-daverandom-and-yusuf-ali)

Answer (score 3):

```
file_get_contents('ftp://username:password@host.com/');
```

Comment: you can see result from here: http://ebookdownload1.com/denemeler/deneme.php . i want to this for user can download this file.

Comment: Do you want them do do this via FTP or HTTP?

Comment: via HTTP. similar to rapidshare.

Comment: @Yusufali: just append /path/to/file after your URL

Comment: this is  my code: echo file_get_contents("ftp://derpost:pass**@ftp1.freakshare.com/Freez%20Screen%20Video%20Capture.lnk"); you can see result in here: http://ebookdownload1.com/denemeler/deneme.php

Comment: im trying this with header() function http://ebookdownload1.com/denemeler/deneme2.php i want similar. But others can't see the address and password.